# How to add additional elements to a datatable row

Tags: c#

```
dTable.Rows.Add("SSN", "Firstname", "Lastname");
```

I want to continue adding elements to the same row as the code above with a for loop, how do i do it ?

EDIT:

Thanks for fast answer! sorry i was unclear with my main question How do i continue to expand the row? I have an array with values "Task 1" "Task 2" "Task 3" etc is it possible to make a loop that expands it like this

dTable.Rows.Add("SSN", "Firstname", "Lastname");

dTable.Rows.Add("SSN", "Firstname", "Lastname", arrTask[0]);

dTable.Rows.Add("SSN", "Firstname", "Lastname" arrTask[0], arrTask[1]);

dTable.Rows.Add("SSN", "Firstname", "Lastname" arrTask[0], arrTask[1], arrTask[2]);

Comment: Well DataTable does not support this, unless you add more columns

Comment: The columns are already there for all task, the rows are just empty and i want to put data into them.

Comment: Yes, it still works, I have edited my answer using object[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this code inside loop:

```
var row = dTable.NewRow();
row.ItemArray = new object[] {"SSN", "Firstname", "Lastname"};

dTable.Rows.Add(row);
```

**Edit**: In case you want to add values in existing row:

```
row.ItemArray = row.ItemArray.Concat(arrTask)
                            .ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for fast answer!

but i was unclear with my main question

How do i continue to expand the row? I have an array with values "Task 1" "Task 2" "Task 3" etc

is it possible to make a for loop that expands it like this

dTable.Rows.Add("SSN", "Firstname", "Lastname");

dTable.Rows.Add("SSN", "Firstname", "Lastname", arrTask[0]);

dTable.Rows.Add("SSN", "Firstname", "Lastname" arrTask[0], arrTask[1]);

dTable.Rows.Add("SSN", "Firstname", "Lastname" arrTask[0], arrTask[1], arrTask[2]);

Comment: @user1693991: could you update your question? the format in here is not good

Comment: Thx for another fast answer, but i was unclear again.
The SSN, firstname and lastname values are already in the row while the next 3 cells are empty. I want to add data on the empty ones only. I dont want to change the SSN, firstname and lastname values. The columns are SSN, FirstName, LastName, task1, task2 and task3. The first row has the following values, xxxxxxxx, MyFirstName, MyLastName, and there are 3 empty cells which i want to add data into them with a loop.

Comment: Thanks for another fast answer, i really appreciate ur help!

but i need to go now, so i try your new code example later, i let you know the result later.

Answer (score 0):

This code will allow you add the rows

```
DataRow newRow=dTable.NewRow();

newRow["ColName1"] = "SSN";

newRow["ColName2"] = "Firstname";

newRow["ColName3"] = "Lastname";

dTable.Rows.Add(row);
```